# MySQLi second query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with MySQLi and PHP while trying to use query twice inside one php page. The problem is that first query works perfect but second don't work. First query set the session, but second don't. Here is my code (I also have connect to db file, form and other files)..

```
$connection = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];   

if($select1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")) {
    $counter1 = $select1->num_rows;
    if($counter1 != 0) {
        $_SESSION["accesserror"] = "Error: <em>That username is already used by other member.</em>";
    }
}
else if($select2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email'")) {
    $counter2 = $select2->num_rows;
    if($counter2 != 0) {
        $_SESSION["accesserror"] = "Eror: <em>That E-Mail is already used by other member.</em>";
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of setting a variable, display the real error (best practices examples for `mysqli` ) . Also, don't sql inject your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `else if`

```
else if($select2 = $connection->query("SELECT * ...
```

With an `if`

```
if($select2 = $connection->query("SELECT * ...
```

The problem with your code is that execution can never enter the `else if` so long as the first query was run successfully (even if the 1st query returns no result, it is still run successfully).  In order to always check both conditions, you need to separate those two in separate `if` blocks

PS: It would be even more efficient to run one query, and you should *never* insert user supplied values such as `$username` directly in your queries; this is to avoid SQL injection. Your code is very vulnerable. Here is a safer, more efficient version:

```
$username = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";
if($select = $connection->query($sql) && $select->num_rows) {
    while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['username']===$username){/* add the "username taken" error */}
        if($row['email']===$email){/*add the "email taken" error */}
    }
}elseif($select===false){
    //Todo: handle server error. probably a badly formed query
    //error details in $connection->error
}else{
    // OK to register
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help and advices.

Comment: @dovlapsy You're welcome. I've added some code to my solution. If I helped you solve your problem, be sure to select my solution and upvote; that's how we thank helpers here.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I selected your solution but can't upvote utnil I reach 15 reputation. Thanks for code you posted, but I wanted to users know exactly what is wrong (username or email) so I had to use 2 queries. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: @dovlapsy I would still use one query and just parse the results. See my updated answer.  Note that your current code, even with the fix I first suggested, will never show both errors if the `username` AND `email` are both taken. That's because `$_SESSION["accesserror"] =...` will overwrite the first error when it sets the second.